# Big Data in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sql, list, sharepoint-2010, bigdata, splist

I have a big amount of data (7 Mio. rows) in CSV-Format I have to import into a SharePoint-Project once in a month automaticly. The total amount of data is not that big (100 kB). The query in that data usually only retrieves one or a few rows)

Because SharePoint does not really "like" big lists (Threshold etc.) I wonder which would be the best way to solve that bottleneck.

1. Just put the Data into the List 
   (Would not prefer this, cause even the deletion before import would surely take hours)
2. Save the data into a sql-Database and write a "wrapper" to connect to SQL directly

These are my first thoughts about the possibility to solve this. Are there any other (better) approaches?

Answer (score 1):

I would use SSIS to do this.

Download the SharePoint list adapters for SSIS (just do a google search for these).

Use a flat file connection to get the data from your csv file, and you can compare the data already in your sharepoint list to the data in the csv file and add only the new rows - I think you use a merge/join to do this.

I've done this before, let me know if you need more details, this is just off the top of my head.